# maximum/minimum on incrementing buttons

Tags: swift, max, increment, min

I'm fairly new to Xcode/Swift and am wondering how to set a maximum and minimum for amounts that result in a plus and minus button being touched. My existing code is below. The notifyBeforeAvailabilty I want to go from 1-20 and the ratePerMinute I want to go from $0.00 to $15.00.

```
var notifyBeforeAvailability: Int!
var ratePerMin: Float!


notifyBeforeAvailability = 1
updateNotifyBeforeAvailability()
ratePerMin = 0.10
updateRatePerMin()


 @IBAction func notifyBeforeAvailabilityPlus(sender: AnyObject) {
    notifyBeforeAvailability = notifyBeforeAvailability + 1
    updateNotifyBeforeAvailability()
}
@IBAction func notifyBeforeAvailabilityMinus(sender: AnyObject) {
    notifyBeforeAvailability = notifyBeforeAvailability - 1
    updateNotifyBeforeAvailability()
}
func updateNotifyBeforeAvailability() {
    lblNotifyTime.text = String(notifyBeforeAvailability) + "min"
}


@IBAction func ratePerMinPlus(sender: AnyObject) {
    ratePerMin = ratePerMin + 0.10
    updateRatePerMin()
}    
@IBAction func ratePerMinMinus(sender: AnyObject) {
    ratePerMin = ratePerMin - 0.10
    updateRatePerMin()
}
func updateRatePerMin() {
    let currentValue = ratePerMin
    let current_string = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%.2f", currentValue)
    lblYourRate.text = "$" + current_string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min` & `max` for clamping values. Something like:

```
notifyBeforeAvailability = min(max(1, notifyBeforeAvailability + 1), 20)
// In this example 1 & 20 are your bounds
// set the others accordingly...
```

Also, you could avoid to format numbers yourself by utilizing [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter)

By the way... In case you're using [`UIStepper`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistepper) controls, there are `minimumValue` & `maximumValue` (along with a `stepValue`) properties that handle limits for you...

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked perfectly! No UIStepper just regular buttons. I'm not sure about the NSNumberFormatter part, is that something I should be using? I'm kind of a newbie here.

Comment: @jessicamele Yes, `NSNumberFormatter` is definitely something that you should be using. You can find plenty of documentation regarding it as well. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The Alladinian's answer is right, but I prefer use didSet in var and from there call  the functions.

```
var notifyBeforeAvailability : Int = 1 {

    didSet {

        if oldValue < 1 {

            self.notifyBeforeAvailability = 1
        }
        if oldValue > 20 {

            self.notifyBeforeAvailability = 20
        }

        updateNotifyBeforeAvailability()

    }

}

var ratePerMin : Float = 0.10 {

    didSet{

        if newValue < 0.0{

            self.ratePerMin = 0.0
        }
        if newValue > 15.0 {

            self.ratePerMin = 15.0
        }
        print(newValue)
        updateRatePerMin()
    }

}
@IBAction func notifyBeforeAvailabilityPlus(sender: AnyObject) {
    notifyBeforeAvailability  += 1
}
@IBAction func notifyBeforeAvailabilityMinus(sender: AnyObject) {
    notifyBeforeAvailability -= 1
}
func updateNotifyBeforeAvailability() {
    lblNotifyTime.text = String(notifyBeforeAvailability) + "min"
}


@IBAction func ratePerMinPlus(sender: AnyObject) {
    ratePerMin += 0.10
}
@IBAction func ratePerMinMinus(sender: AnyObject) {
    ratePerMin -= 0.10
}
func updateRatePerMin() {
    let currentValue = ratePerMin
    let current_string = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%.2f", currentValue)
    lblYourRate.text = "$" + current_string
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rroobb is there any benefit to doing it in this way, as I said I'm kind if a newbie here.